# Update YugabyteDB config when deploying through terraform module

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We have setup our 3 node cluster using the official yugabyte terraform module.  We need to update the flag file for tserver to enable authenticatoin, what is the right way to add flags to flagfile and safely restart tserver accross all nodes. The cluster is not yet deployed for production
https://github.com/yugabyte/terraform-aws-yugabyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `template file` https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile
and state store together to get the gflag version control. Terraform is not a real good solution to control gflags though. You may want another tool for this like ansible to control gflag state and process rolling restart.